# JDBC Type2 Diver

Tags: ojdbc

I'm new to JDBC java programming.
While trying to connect to oracle database ( 10.2 ) using OCI driver, getting below error:

C:\JavaPractise\JDBC>java Type2_Driver_Demo_1
Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:672)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:346)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:78)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Type2_Driver_Demo_1.main(Type2_Driver_Demo_1.java:9)
```

I have set CLASSPATH to ojdbc14.jar
Also oracle_home and TNS_ADMIN are set to point to tnsnames.ora file.
Below is JDBC URL:

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@XE","scott","tiger");

Can you assist on this error.
Just FYI:
Type 4 driver working fine.

Thanks,
Tejas S Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

10.2 is a very old version. Can you try to use the [latest version of the database and client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html)? 21c